# how can I get the firebase database data in a nested location using python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have this database structure

[image]

Each business ID has an inventory, in that inventory, there are many items and each item has many attributes like name, part number and NSN. 
I need to get all the NSNs for each inventory item into an array so I tried this code and other variations of it

```
db = firebase.database() 
Businesses = db.child("Businesses").get()
for user in Businesses.each():
userid = user.key()
inventorydb = db.child("Businesses").child(userid).child("Inventory").get()

 #looping through inventory child

for item in inventorydb.each():
    itemid = item.key()
    itemdb = db.child("Businesses").child(userid).child("Inventory").child(itemid).get()
print(itemdb.val("NSN"))
```

but all i keep getting is this error

```
val() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

how can I get all the NSNs for each inventory item?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at the documentation, the `val()` function returns a dictionary of that snapshot

You probably want

```
print(itemdb.val()["NSN"])
```

I would also recommend rewriting your Firebase structure to "[avoid building nests](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-denormalizing-data)"